# Streams in Java 8: simple solution to use parallelstream() on a cluster?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, cluster-computing, java-stream

`parallelstream()` provides seamless parallelization of operations on the stream across the cores of a single machine.

How can I extend this logic so that `parallelstream()` distributes these operations to all the machines of a cluster?

Ideally:
- I create a cluster of machines, using framework ??
- launching a `myCollection.parallelstream().filter(something).collect()` distributes the job to all cores of all machines of the cluster and returns the result to the machine piloting the cluster.

Comment: You'd need to provide your own `ForkJoinPool` if I recall correctly

Comment: I have barely started adapting to Java 8 and people are already talking about stuff like this. I am lagging behind ;)

Comment: :-) well, in the excellent book "Java 8 in Action", authors keep saying that the principles of parallelization across cores hold just as well for parallelization across machines: so I just hope this delivers!

Comment: @seinecle I don't think it is that simple ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing

Comment: Look into using Cilk. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus That project was designed for clusters. The F/J framework was modeled on that project to work on SMP computers, not clusters.

Comment: No, this isn't a thing that can be done straightforwardly or possibly at all out of the box.

Comment: ok, I suppose the closest is using Spark with the syntax of Java 8 then.

Comment: Have a look at Oracle Coherence (commercial), which supports this out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark seems to do what you want ie distribute work over nodes. The dsl looks similar to java 8 streams. 
You can also have a look to akka streams. With akka streams doesn't allow you to do what you want out of the box but it offers you a toolbox to help you with a nice dsl.